# JPA for Graphdatabases

Tags: jpa, graph-databases

I thought about using a graph database for my new project. It's 
a project with many social relations and many other things which 
can easily be represented by a graph.

Graph-Databases are much faster so I started thinking about it.

However, I have a Java Enterprise Web Application and I have been using
(until now) a relational MySQL Database with JPA.

Now my question: Is there already the same JPA functionallity
for Graph-Databases like there is for relational Databases?

I would like to use [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/) or [OrientDB](http://www.orientdb.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataNucleus JPA provides [persistence to Neo4j](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/datastores/neo4j.html). Supports basic relationships and an amount of Cypher query capabilities, and there is a [tutorial for use with JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/guides/tutorial_neo4j.html) (as well as JDO). Open to contributions to push it further.

OrientDB also provides an amount of support for JPA annotations direct IIRC.